# I can run my program from launchpad but can't put icon in panel

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, plasma

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04.  I developed a C++/Qt program. The executable is pnotes. I found a suitable icon, wrote pnotes.desktop, and put that file in ~/.local/share/plasma_icons. 
Now, the launcher allows me to  "run pnotes" but it does not show the icon and it does not allow me to drag the icon for pnotes to the panel.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Nevermind! I was in the wrong directory. When I put pnotes.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications  instead of .local/share/plasma_icons  I got the launcher behavior I wanted.